# WPF - Open UserControl as a new dialog without freezing the main

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a button, which can enable my UserControl. UserControl will display some report and other stuff, and is located in the storyboard.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Reports"
                                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="ActiveReport">
                        <DiscreteInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="1"/>
                    </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Now I want to add a possibility to open this UserControl as a new dialog, if button is clicked with right mouse button.

I binded method BtnClick to this button:

```
<Button MouseRightButtonUp="BtnClick">
     ...
</Button>
```

And then create a new window with this UserControl as a content:

```
private void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Window window = new Window
    {
        Content = new MyUserContent()
    };

    window.ShowDialog();
}
```

Then it is possible to open a new window with needed UserControl by right click. The problem is that if a new window is opened, then I can't use the main one anymore. It just freezes and I can't select it until I close the opened window. I want to be able to use both windows where two this UserControls are used.

Update:

Using window.Show() instead of window.ShowDialog() will solve the problem. Thanks to @Darshan.

Comment: Use window.Show(); instead of window.ShowDialog();

Comment: @Darshan Thanks, that was easy and this solved the problem.

But now controls in new window and in the main are connected with each others, and I can't work with them independently.

Comment: Ok, next problem is connected to UserCode content and I should solve it by myself. Thanks.

Comment: you want to automatically update value on main window when you update value on user control ???

Comment: No, they should works independently.

Comment: so whats the problem ?